# Do I need to clean up memory myself in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, memory, xamarin.forms

I have a login page. After authorization, the user is taken to another page.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
 {
     Application.Current.MainPage = new Main_Page();
 });
```

Should I somehow clear the memory allocated for the login page?

Comment: no, GC will take care of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at Xamarin PageRenderer code [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/6d3c41fb2dc0911979cbddda4987e8f76ef7845f/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/PageRenderer.cs). Xamarin `Page` class has Dispose() method implemented. So Page should be clean up by GC.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not, it is done automatically.